# ACR122L revert from card read mode

Tags: nfc, smartcard-reader

I am working with the ACS ACR122L contactless reader and have come across the following issue.

If send an APDU to the device to read a card then the reader goes into read mode to read a card that is presented. This is fine if a card is presented, but if a card is never presented then the device seems to hang in "Read Mode".

When stuck in "Read Mode" I cannot send any further APDUs or open/close a connection.

I have looked at setting the timeouts with no avail. All these do is set the amount of time the library waits for a response (blocks), before moving on. The reader state doesn't change.

The only way I can revert to "Ready Mode" is to power cycle the device or present a card.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first check if a card is available. If the reader gets stuck, then by all means reset the device. Normally card readers don't hold much state, so resetting the device programmatically should not be such an issue (if you can do this programmatically, of course). It's strange behavior none the less.

Comment: I have figured out how to poll for a card but am having a similar issue with putting it in P2P intiator mode. Have you developed for this device? Thanks @owlstead

Comment: Not that I remember, I can only dig into my generic knowledge about card readers...